# Unable to get NVidia 9600GT working with Kubuntu 14.04

Tags: x11, nvidia, graphic-card

Problem:  Nvidia drivers are not loading

Hardware:  Dell T110

Graphics Card

```
root@madeye:~# lspci | grep VGA
02:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation G96 [GeForce 9500 GT] (rev a1)
```

Nvidia Packages Installed

```
root@madeye:~# dpkg --get-selections | grep nvidia
nvidia-304                  deinstall
nvidia-304-updates              install
nvidia-current-updates              install
nvidia-libopencl1-304               deinstall
nvidia-libopencl1-304-updates           install
nvidia-opencl-icd-304               deinstall
nvidia-opencl-icd-304-updates           install
nvidia-settings                 install
```

I have updated all packages after the install and installed kernel-headers

Relevant lines from `Xorg.0.log`:

```
[    19.739] (II) LoadModule: "nvidia"
[    19.739] (II) Loading /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules/nvidia_drv.so
[    19.740] (II) Module nvidia: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[    19.740]    compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
[    19.740]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    19.774] (EE) NVIDIA: Failed to load the NVIDIA kernel module. Please check your
[    19.774] (EE) NVIDIA:     system's kernel log for additional error messages.
[    19.774] (II) UnloadModule: "nvidia"
[    19.774] (II) Unloading nvidia
[    19.774] (EE) Failed to load module "nvidia" (module-specific error, 0)Ke
```

Relevant lines from `kern.log`:

```
Jun 28 16:05:12 madeye kernel: [   19.835310] NVRM: This PCI I/O region assigned to your NVIDIA device is invalid:
Jun 28 16:05:12 madeye kernel: [   19.835310] NVRM: BAR1 is 0M @ 0x0 (PCI:0000:02:00.0)
Jun 28 16:05:12 madeye kernel: [   19.835318] NVRM: The system BIOS may have misconfigured your GPU.
Jun 28 16:05:12 madeye kernel: [   19.835325] nvidia: probe of 0000:02:00.0 failed with error -1
Jun 28 16:05:12 madeye kernel: [   19.835361] NVRM: The NVIDIA probe routine failed for 1 device(s).
Jun 28 16:05:12 madeye kernel: [   19.835364] NVRM: None of the NVIDIA graphics adapters were initialized!
Jun 28 16:05:12 madeye kernel: [   19.875318] NVRM: This PCI I/O region assigned to your NVIDIA device is invalid:
Jun 28 16:05:12 madeye kernel: [   19.875318] NVRM: BAR1 is 0M @ 0x0 (PCI:0000:02:00.0)
Jun 28 16:05:12 madeye kernel: [   19.875324] NVRM: The system BIOS may have misconfigured your GPU.
Jun 28 16:05:12 madeye kernel: [   19.875328] nvidia: probe of 0000:02:00.0 failed with error -1
Jun 28 16:05:12 madeye kernel: [   19.875348] NVRM: The NVIDIA probe routine failed for 1 device(s).
Jun 28 16:05:12 madeye kernel: [   19.875350] NVRM: None of the NVIDIA graphics adapters were initialized!
```

What further troubleshooting steps to I need to take?   What can I do to get the kernel to recognize the graphics card?

---

**EDIT**

As per terdon's answer, if I run the command, I get the below message:

```
dthacker@madeye:~$ sudo apt-get install nvidia-kernel-dkms nvidia-xconfig nvidia-settings
Reading package lists... Done 
Building dependency tree Reading state information... Done 
Package nvidia-kernel-dkms is not available, but is referred to by another package. 
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source 
E: Package 'nvidia-kernel-dkms' has no installation candidate 
E: Unable to locate package nvidia-xconfig`
```

@terdon, I used this utility from the article you pointed me towards:

```
root@madeye:~# ubuntu-drivers devices | grep recommended
driver   : nvidia-331 - distro non-free recommended
```

I then installed nvidia-331 and the restricted drivers utility shows that it is being used. The nvidia GUI utility still has no options visible for configuring multiple monitors (there are currently two connected to the card) and I am still getting errors in the `kern.log` saying the Nvidia init module failed.

Still working towards a solution...

Output of `apt-get install nvidia-driver`:

```
root@madeye:~# apt-get install nvidia-driver
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package nvidia-driver is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source`
```

Comment: Ah, sorry, the `nvidia-kernel-dkms` package does not seem to exist for Ubuntu and is actually probably obsolete. Try reading through [Installing Nvidia Drivers](http://askubuntu.com/q/61396) there are some useful tips there.

Comment: First, what is your kernel version? Also, can you outline what procedure you used to install the drivers? Also, output of `dpkg -l | grep nvidia` please. Also, what version of Kubuntu?

Comment: Usually, I use module-assistant. This should work. Install it, then type `m-a` and then follow the prompts. I think you need to install `nvidia-kernel-source` first possibly. Actually, just install the meta-package `nvidia-driver`.

Comment: Note `nvidia-driver` is only available in more recent Ubuntu variants. It is not in wheezy for example.

Comment: @FaheemMitha, my kernel is version 3.13.0-30-generic and the output of dpkg is in the initial post.

Comment: Ok. Try installing `nvidia-driver`.

Comment: @FaheemMitha, that package is shown as obsolete.

Comment: Shown by what? It's a meta-package.

Comment: @terdon I have used this utility from the article you pointed me to and got this

Answer (score 0):

For those who arrive here with a similar problem. My kubuntu (21.01) install failed to boot -- getting stuck on ASUS logo.
Alt-F2 brought up a command prompt but the only error in dmesg was repeats of: `EDAC skx: ECC is disabled on imc 0`

Following the advice above, I used:
`ubuntu-drivers devices | grep recommended`

From the recommended driver, I installed:
`sudo apt-get install nvidia-driver-470`

After a reboot, everything is fine. Happy days. The ECC errors are still there, but I will suppress those.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).